# Can sitting water in toilet bowl leak to downstairs?

Tags: leak, toilet, leaking, leaks

I live in a high-rise apartment building. Recently, the super came knocking on my door and told me that downstairs neighbor suffered from water leaks in their bathroom ceiling. They believe it's from my toilet's gasket wax seal being broken. We stopped using the toilet immediately. However, the next day, downstairs neighbor reported that the leak got worse. We told the super that we didn't use our toilet. The super said, even though we didn't use it, the sitting water in the toilet bowl can leak to downstairs constantly. It seems nonsense to me. As the sitting water in toilet bowl is very still. No water flows from tank into the bowl unless there is a flush.

Is my super making sense or imagining things? I don't want to waste money on fixing a problem in a wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that water drains from a toilet bowl outside of the flush. You could use a used food can as a dipper to remove most of the standing water in the toilet bowl and a sponge to get the rest out. The leak below will probably continue even without any water in the toilet.

Comment: The actual way to test is to turn off the supply water to the toilet and flush it. Wait a few days and see what happens downstairs.

Comment: The only way water could drain is if you have a leak between tank and bowl, or the temperature is swinging wildly (enough to change the density of the water, and extremely unlikey).  So the former.  You could have a leaky flush valve that's allowing water into the bowl, or perhaps a leaky gasket at the tank-bowl interface.